# Error in R shiny subsetting dataframe based on CSV file

Tags: r, csv, shiny, subset

I Am creating a dynamic update in R shiny with the following code using the iris dataset

```
 write.csv(iris, file = "iris.csv", row.names = F)
# to create a local version of iris dataset

# next create UI


  ui <- fluidPage(


   fileInput("file", "Browse",
        accept = c("text/csv",
                   "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                   ".csv")
    ),
   selectInput(inputId = "Speciesname", label = "Name",choices = 
    NULL,selected = NULL),
   tableOutput("data")
   )


   #Create server
    server <- function(input, output,session) {



 df = reactive({
 req(input$file)
 return(read.csv(input$file$datapath))
 })

  observe({
  choices1 = unique(df()$Species)
  updateSelectInput(session,"Speciesname", choices =  choices1)
  })
  output$data <- renderTable({
  req(input$Speciesname)
  df[as.character(input$Speciesname), ]
  }, )
   }


 #Run app
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am able to read the file in. The subsetting however is showing the following error and the shiny app

```
 Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
 [No stack trace available]
```

I am unable to understand or sort this error out. The code runs when I dont use a local copy of the dataset but use the built in R iris dataset. I request someone to guide me here

Comment: it should be `df()`, as in `df()[as.character(input$Speciesname), ]`

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have made the correction but now I am only getting NA values in all rows of the output. The colun headings appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job

```
library(shiny)
write.csv(iris, file = "iris.csv", row.names = F)
# to create a local version of iris dataset

# next create UI

ui <- fluidPage(


  fileInput("file", "Browse",
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),
  selectInput(inputId = "Speciesname", label = "Name",choices = 
                NULL,selected = NULL),
  tableOutput("data")
)


#Create server
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  df = reactive({
    req(input$file)
    return(read.csv(input$file$datapath))
  })

  observe({
    choices1 = unique(df()$Species)
    updateSelectInput(session,"Speciesname", choices =  choices1)
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({
    req(input$Speciesname)
    df()[df()$Species %in% input$Speciesname,]
  })
}


#Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Is the %in% operator essential

Comment: Yes, its a better version of `==` it will take care of multiple matches, if any. For example if you have 2 species selected and want them to be displayed it easier to have this operator instead of writing `==` twice

Comment: Lovely. Thank You Sir